# How to find variable names in Bash source code

Tags: bash, parsing, variables, module, namespaces

I'm writing an experimental Bash module system that would allow local function namespaces, and my first idea was to write a Bash function parser that would read the function code line by line and prepend each function/variable name with `<module-name>.` (i.e. function `func` in module `module` would become `module.func` - which could again be imported in another module like `module_2.module.func` and so on; variables inside functions would be name-mangled - variable `var` within function `func` in module `module` would become `__module_func_var`).

However, in order to do that, I need a way to detect which names are variables and replace all their occurences in the function with the transported import-name. Trivial cases like `variable=[...]` are easily parsable, but there are countless of other cases where it's not that trivial - what about `while read variable; do [...] done` and `variable2="asdf${variable//_/+}"`?

It seems to me that in order to do this I need to dive into the parsing mechanisms of Bash or read a book on programming languages - but where do I start in order to achieve what I have explained above?

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way to detect which names are variables

I'm sorry to say this, but in general it's impossible.

Supporting only the *static* cases where variables can occur is possible but very tricky. Consider only variable assignments: Besides `x=` there are `declare x=`, `printf -v x`, `read x`, `mapfile x`, `readarray x` and probably many more. Even mature tools like `shellcheck` still have problems parsing all these cases correctly (for instance, see [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1599)).

However, even if you mastered parsing all the *static* cases correctly there still could by *dynamic* variables, for instance:

```
x=$(someCommand)
declare "$x=something"
```

In this example you cannot know the name of the new variable without executing `someCommand`. Other things which are equally (or even) worse are `bash`'s indirection operator `${!x}`, implicit indirection in arithmetic contexts (e.g. `x=y; echo $((x))`), and `eval`.

**tl;dr:** The only way to get all the variables in a script is to interpret/execute the script.

But here comes another problem: Executing the script is also not an option if there is non-determinism (`declare "$(tr -cd a-z /dev/urandom | head -c1)=..."`). Note that user-input is also non-deterministic (`read x; declare "var$x=..."`). You would have to write a static analyzer. But this is also not an option because of the halting problem. From the halting problem we can deduce that it is (in general) impossible to tell whether a given bash script has a finite amount of variables.

---

To implement your module system you could use another approach. For instance, if someone wants to implement a module for your framework then they have to specify the functions/variables in this module in an easy parsable format.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be tricky. Now that I think about it, doing such parsing completely correct would require solution to the halting problem - as one could easily write a Turing Machine in Bash and implement a function like this: `if halts_on TM input; then declare "var$x=..."; else declare "car$x=...`...

Creating a special syntax was not my original plan, as nobody likes learning new syntax, and the parser would become a dependency on the script. I kinda wanted it to fit in the current Bash implementation.